# What is the most accurate polygenic score for Alzheimer’s disease?

Tags: genetics, molecular-genetics, brain, human-genetics, gene

To date, which polygenic score (i.e. which study) has produced the largest effect size for Alzheimer’s prediction in out-of-sample validation?